# LDAP bind error accessing AD: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am new to LDAP, and fairly new to PHP; I'm trying to access Active Directory.   The following ldapsearch command works at a shell prompt:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://healthdiagnostics.local -b ou='All HD Users',dc=healthdiagnostics,dc=local -D admin.mchristie@healthdiagnostics.local -w 'mypassword'
```

so I assume that means that healthdiagnostics.local is accepting LDAP requests.  In PHP, if I do this:

```
$ds = ldap_connect("ldap://healthdiagnostics.local");
```

I get success, but my understanding is that ldap_connect will return success on anything that parses as a URL, so that doesn't tell me much.  Then for the bind:

```
$r=ldap_bind($ds,'admin.mchristie@healthdiagnostics.local','mypassword');
```

which gives me this error:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /var/www/webapp.hmca2.com/public_html/terms.php on line 24
```

Some searching and reading made me think I needed a connection string, so I tried these:

```
$r=ldap_bind($ds,'uid=admin.mchristie@healthdiagnostics.local,ou=Administrators,dc=healthdiagnostics,dc=local', 'password');
$r=ldap_bind($ds,'uid=admin.mchristie,ou=Administrators,dc=healthdiagnostics,dc=local','password');
```

with the same result.  This makes me think I don't have a successful connection from the ldap_connect step, but I don't see how to figure out the problem.  Searching old answers here I found a suggestion to add "TLS_REQUEST allow" to 
ldap.conf, which I've done to no benefit.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Determining%20the%20FDN

Comment: @jwilleke Thanks; I tried that and used the string I got, but that didn't work.  According to example code [here](http://www.oit.uci.edu/idm/campusids/ldap-query-code-example-php/) I should just be using the username with no connection string.  I tried "admin.mchristie@healthdiagnostics.local" as the user, and also healthdiagnostics.local\\admin.mchristie, which is the format in the example; neither worked.

Comment: The username will only work if it is the same as the samAccountName.

Answer (score -1):

To enable LDAP, you would also need to install a CA certificate for the LDAP and update your LDAP configuration file with the certificate information.  There are some guides online depending on what OS you are using.

Comment: @TobySpeight However, you don't need code...just follow the commands to create your CA...however you prefer to create your CA and update your config file accordingly...there is no need to code.